# Prove: If S is countably infinite set, all finite subsets of S are also countably infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Question: Prove that if S is a countably infinite set then all the finite subsets of S are also countably infinite.

Where would I start?

Comment: Do you mean that the **set of** all finite subsets of $S$ **is** countably infinite -- or (as Nilknarf assumed) that each **infinite** subset of $S$ is (by itself) _countably_ infinite?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361320/neatest-proof-that-set-of-finite-subsets-is-countable

Comment: No, all the finite subsets are not infinite because each of them is finite.  None of them are infinite for all of themare finite.