# How do I prove that a set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable?

Tags: proof-explanation

Let $X$ be the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Thus some elements of $X$ include $\emptyset$ and $\{1, 5, 9\}$ and $\{3, 346\}$ and $\{1\}$; however, the set of even natural numbers is not an element of $X$. Prove that $X$ is countable.

I think I might need to prove that all sets of $X$ are countable and there's a countable number of sets, but I'm not sure. I also don't know what " the set of even natural numbers is not an element of $X$. Prove that $X$ is countable" means?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.   The set of even natural numbers is not an element of $X$, because that set is not a *finite* subset of $\mathbb N$

Comment: "The set of even natural numbers is not an element of $X$" means that the set $\{0,2,4,6,\dots\} \notin X$. This is because it's not a finite set.

Comment: "Prove that $X$ is countable" means that you need to prove that $X$ is a countable set, it does not mean you need to prove every element of $X$ is countable. You're trying to prove that there are only countably many finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Do you know that a (finite) product of countable sets is countable, and the union of countably many countable sets is countable?

Comment: Thank you guys so much!

Comment: Also, cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200389/show-that-the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-mathbbn-is-countable) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361320/neatest-proof-that-set-of-finite-subsets-is-countable)

Comment: No, I don't really know that a (finite) product of countable sets is countable, or that the union of countable sets is countable. We didn't go over it in class yet. Is there a way to systematically enumerate X?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find a map $\phi: \mathbb N \to X$ which is surjective. Then you are done.
The Set of uneven numbers is not in $X$ because that set would be infinite.

You can first look at the case of a fixed $n\in \mathbb N$ and then realise that there are countable infinitely many subsets of $\mathbb N$ that have $n$ elements by finding a surcjective map $\phi_n : \mathbb N \to X_n$. Where $X_n$ are those subsets of length $n$. ($\mathbb N^n \cong \mathbb N$)

If you have that you can define $\Phi: \mathbb N^2 \to X; (n,m) \mapsto \phi_n(m)$ and note that $\mathbb N^2$ is itself countably finite.

Answer (score 0):

It is already answered, but you can also write a 1-1 map from $X$  to $\mathbb{N}$ to prove it. Let $p_k$ be the $k$-th prime number, so $p_1 = 2$, $p_2 = 3$, ... Define $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as follows. Any element of $X$ is a finite subset of the set of natural numbers of the form $A=\{n_1, n_2, ..., n_k\}$ where $n_1 < n_2 < ... < n_k$. Define $$f(A) = {p_1}^{n_1} ... {p_k}^{n_k}$$ Then $f$ is one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

If $P(A)$ denote the power set of $A$, you can write $X$ as follows:

$$X = \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} \{ Y : Y\in P(\{1,2,\dots ,k\}) \}$$

So X is countable union of countable sets, hence countable.