# cardinality of some subsets of the power sets of $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, cardinals

What is the cardinal number of these sets :

1. $X:= \left\{ A \in P(\mathbb Z) \mid \sum_{a \in A} |a| \text{ is finite} \right\}$
2. $Y:= \left\{ B \in P(\mathbb R) \mid(\mathbb {R}\setminus B) \space \text {is countable} \right\}$
3. $Z:= \left\{ C \in P(\mathbb R) \mid|C| = \mathfrak{c}  \right\}$

My solutions:

$1.$ Define $ f : \left\{x\in P(\mathbb Z) | \text {x is finite subset}\right\}  \to \mathbb N$

$\space \text{defined by :} \begin{cases}  
  P_{lastdigit7}  \space ,  & \text{if $y\in x>0$} \\
  P_{lastdigit3},  & \text{if $y\in x<0$} \\\end{cases} $
so $f(X) = P_{y1}*P_{y2}* \cdots * P_{yn}$

$Py:=$ the prime number in the y place  , $P_1 = 2 , P_2=3$ and so on..

$P_{lastdigit7}:=$ the prime number in the y place  when last digit is 7 $P_1 = 7 , P_2=17$...

$P_{lastdigit3}:=$ the prime number in the y place  when last digit is 3 $P_1 = 3 
  , P_2=13$...

I think its a bijection and its prove that is countable , $\aleph_0$.

2.We want $(\mathbb {R}\setminus B)$ to be countable so $B$ must be
uncountable .

so lets find cardinality of countable sets.

High limit : $|\mathbb R ^{\mathbb N}| = \mathfrak{c}.$

Low limit: $| \left\{0,1 \right\} ^{\mathbb N}| = \mathfrak{c}$.

So $|Y|=\mathfrak{c}$.

$P(\mathbb R)=\left\{ Countable \space subsets \right\} \bigcup  \left\{ 
  Uncountable \space subsets \right\} \implies $

$2^\mathfrak{c}=|P(\mathbb R)|=|\left\{ Countable \space subsets 
  \right\}| +  |\left\{ Uncountable \space subsets \right\}| = $

$\mathfrak{c} + |\left\{ Uncountable \space subsets \right\}| \implies 
  |\left\{ Uncountable \space subsets \right\}|=2^\mathfrak{c}. $

$|Y|=2^\mathfrak{c}.$

$3.$ In excercise 2 we show that $|C|=2^\mathfrak{c}.$

Is my proofs correct ?

Comment: What does $x<0$ mean when we have finite $x\in P(\mathbb Z)?$

Comment: Sorry , fixed it.

Comment: The title is poorly phrased.  Your problems concern the cardinality of some subsets of the power sets of $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb R$.

Comment: You're right that $\mathbb{R}\backslash B$ being countable implies $B$ uncountable, but the inverse implication isn't correct.

Comment: What is $y,$ given $x?$ $f$ is certainly not onto, since the value of $f$ seem to be always primes, but I’m having a hard time finding a reading of your definition of $f$ which makes it one-to-one.

Comment: What is $f(x)$ when $x=\{-1,1\}?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Hope now its clear

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Please ,can you give me an exlpanation why the inverse implication isn't correct ?

Comment: What is $f^{-1}(4)$ in (1)?

Comment: @erez the inverse implication isn't correct, because for say $B = [0, 1]$ both $B$ and $\mathbb R \setminus B$ are uncountable.

Comment: Such an $f$ will be one-to-one, but not onto. No number divisible by $71$ is in the image of $f.$ Neither is any value other divisible by a square $>1.$

Comment: @mihaild You are right , $f^-1(4)$ is not exist. Maybe i can to define f on specific subset of N or find something else?  I'll be glad for some help .Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Maybe i can to define f on specific subset of N or find something else?  I'll be glad for some help .Thanks.

Comment: @mihaild I'll be glad for some help , In excercise 2 maybe i can found the cardinality of countable subset and thats it ?

Comment: For (1), it is easier if you replace $\mathbb Z$ with $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\dots\}.$ We can show that $X$ has a simple bijection with $$X’=\{x\in P(\mathbb N)\mid x\text{ finite}\}$$ using any bijection $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb N.$ Then use binary numbers to encode the elements of $X’.$ https://math.stackexchange.com/a/361677/7933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer for (1) works, modulo some more careful wording, but your $f$ isn’t a bijection.

But $f$ is one-to-one. It is easy to prove that if $W$ is infinite, and there is a one-to-one function $f:W\to\mathbb N,$ then $W$ is countably infinite.

So you don’t need your $f$ to be a bijection to get the cardinality of $X$ is countably infinite.

---

**An explicit bijection for (1).**

If $x=\{a_1<a_2<\cdots <a_k\},$
then define $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x=\emptyset\\\sum_{i=1}^k2^{a_i+1}&a_1\geq 0\\
-1+\sum_{i=1}^k 2^{a_i-2a_1}&a_1<0
\end{cases}$$

This is slightly easier to understand by seeing that $g(x)=f(x)+1$ is a bijection with $\mathbb N^+,$ the set of non-zero natural numbers.

Given $n\in\mathbb N,$ write $n+1$ in binary:

$$n+1=2^{b_1}+2^{b_2}+\cdots+2^{b_k}.$$

With $0\leq b_1<b_2<\cdots<b_k.$

Then if $b_1=0,$ we get:

$$f^{-1}(n)=\{b_2-1,b_3-1,\dots,b_k-1\}$$

When $b_1>0,$ you get: $$f^{-1}(n)=\{b_1-2b_1,b_2-2b_1,b_3-2b_1,\dots b_k-2b_1\}.$$

I’ll leave it to you to prove this is a bijection.

---

This is a tricky way of doing something that is easy for the set $$X’=\{x\in P(\mathbb N)\mid x\text{ finite}\}$$ There is an easy binary encoding of $X’$:

$$f’(x)=\sum_{i\in x} 2^{i}$$

We could just use a simple bijection $g:X\to X’,$ of course, and define $f(x)=f’(g(x)),$ but I wanted a more direct numeric encoding.

Comment: Thank you Thomas !

Answer (score 1):

1. First, let $g$ be any bijection $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb N$, for example
   $$g(n) = \begin{cases} 2 \cdot n,\ n \geq 0\\ -2 \cdot n - 1,\ n < 0\end{cases}$$
   Now, say $f(X) = \sum_{x \in X} 2^{g(x)}$. Check that $f$ is bijection.
2. Let $Y' = \{B \in P(\mathbb R) | B \text{ is countable}\}$. Do you know that $Y'$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$? If yes, then there is simple bijection $Y \leftrightarrow Y'$.
3. Consider set $D = \{[0, 1] \cup T | T \subseteq [3, 4]\}$. What is cardinality of $D$? What is relation between $C$ and $D$?

Comment: 1,2 I understand , and 3 the catdinality is $2^\mathfrak{c} ? $ (because i have $2^\mathfrak{c}$ subsets) , i am not sure...

Comment: Yes. $D$ is essentially subsets of set with cardinality $\mathfrak c$ (adding some elements to all of them doesn't change anything).

Comment: For ex 2 i can take for every subset B in Y' his complement and so  $P(\mathbb R) \setminus B$ is countable? Thank you again !