# Prove that the set of the subsets of N of size n is countable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How can I prove that the set of subsets of N of size n is countable? 
X∈P(N) | |X| = n.
Where do I go on from here?

Also how can I prove that the set of all finite subsets of N is countable.

Comment: Tried to find a function from X to P(N). Pretty sure I'm doing something wrong. Also I'm not looking for a full answer but something to guide me.

Comment: Have you considered induction on n?

Comment: How might I use induction on n? Prove that for n+1  the set of subsets of size n+1 is also true?

Comment: The latter question is addressed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/200389/28900). The former is a ready corollary.

Comment: Do you already know that $\mathbb{N}^{n}$ is countable?  Because if you do, there is a natural map from what you are enumerating to a subset of $\mathbb{N}^{n}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the set of all finite binary sequences — all strings of $0$s and $1$s. There are a few ways to write this set; let's use 
$$
\{0,1\}^{<\omega} := \bigcup_{n<\omega} \{0,1\}^n.
$$
Similarly, the set of all finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ is
$$\mathcal{P}_{<\omega}(\Bbb N) := \bigcup_{n<\omega} \mathcal{P}_n(\Bbb N),
$$
where $\mathcal{P}_n(X)$ is the set of subsets of $X$ of size $n$.

***There is an injection $\{0,1\}^{<\omega} \to \Bbb N$***. 
We can think of a finite binary sequence as a base 2 numeral, but  possibly with $0$s "in front", "on the left", in the high-order positions:  $b_n \dots b_1$. We can have $n=0$, the empty sequence $\varepsilon$. So multiple numerals correspond to the same integer ($\varepsilon_2 = 0_2 = 00_2, 10_2 = 010_2$, etc.) If we put a $1$ in front, however, we get an injection
$$
b_n \dots b_1 \mapsto 2^{n} + \sum_{i=1}^n b_i 2^{i-1}
$$

***There is an injection $\mathcal{P}_{<\omega}(\Bbb N) \to  \{0,1\}^{<\omega}$***.
Given a finite set $A$, let
$$
h(A) = \max_{a\in A} (a + 1),
$$
the least integer greater than everything in $A$.
Thus $h(\emptyset) = 0$, and if $A\ne \emptyset$ then $h(A) = \max(A) + 1$. So $A$ can be represented uniquely by a finite indicator function defined on the integers less than $h(A)$ — in other words, a binary sequence of length $h(A)$, a member of $\{0,1\}^{h(A)}$:
$$
A \mapsto (c_0 \dots c_{h(A) - 1}) \text{ where }c_i = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $i\in A$,} \\
0 &\text{if $i\notin A$.} \\
\end{cases}
$$
*Aside*: The image of this injection is the empty sequence together with all binary sequences that end in a $1$. This is a regular language, $\varepsilon + (\mathbf{0} + \mathbf{1})^* \mathbf{1}$.

Obviously, ***for every $n\ge 0$, there's an injection $\mathcal{P}_{n}(\Bbb N) \to  \mathcal{P}_{<\omega}(\Bbb N)$***, the inclusion map.

So all these sets are countable. In fact, except for $\mathcal{P}_{0}(\Bbb N)$, every set mentioned is countably infinite.