# Cardinality of monotonically decreasing functions

Tags: functions, cardinals

I need to find the cardinality of the following set:

$$
A = \{f \in \mathbb N \to \mathbb N|\forall n, m \in \mathbb N.(n \geq m) \to (f(n) \leq f (m))\}
$$

I'm not sure if $A$ is countable or not. I tried to find an injective function from $P(N)$ to $A$ but couldn't find one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, A is countable. A function $f \in A$ is unique identified by $f(1)$, and its values on a (finite) set of arguments where it changes (the size of that set can be at most $f(1)$, because is it non-increasing). Call this set $V$.

Let $p_i$ denote the i-th prime. Each $f \in A$ maps to a unique natural number $x$ which can be constructed as follows: start with $x=2^{f(1)}$, and for each $v \in V$, multiply $x$ by $p_v^{f(v)}$.

This provides an injective function from $A$ to the natural numbers; the other direction is trivial. So $A$ is a countable set.

Comment: thanks! brilliant. Im still wondering about the other direction though, do I need another function or is there an easier way?

Comment: The other direction is trivial; for $n \in \mathbb N$, take $f$ to be the constant function with value $n$.

Comment: Are you sure it is an injective function? it sounds right but how can I prove that?

Comment: It uses the same idea as for proving that the set of *finite* subsets of $\mathbb N$ is countable, which is explained [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200389/show-that-the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-mathbbn-is-countable). These proofs depend on the fact that every natural numbers has a unique prime factorization (and that there are infinitely many primes).