# Show that the set $ M:= \{ A \subset \mathbb{N}: A $ has infinte many elements } countable is.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As a starting point I have started to use the fact, that every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ countable is. A $\subset \mathbb{N}$ is also a subset of $ \mathbb{N}$ and at this point I can't go forward.

Or can I eventually use somehow Hilbert's Hotel theorem?

I appreciate any help a lot.

Comment: Are you sure the title is correct? I think you meant the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable.

Comment: “Should I show that it is surjective and injective?” You don’t have a function in sight; what could you possibly show is “surjective and injective”?

Comment: It's important to note that "Hilbert's hotel" is not an actual mathematical argument. It's a popularized version of the fact that a function from the natural numbers to itself may be injective without being surjective. Hilbert mentioned it once in 1924, in a popular lecture, and never mentioned it again in his life. The story was picked up in a popular book by physicist George Gamow in 1947, and now has mindshare among religious charlatans (William Lane Craig) to make a point about infinite regress; and many people, philosophers and math students,  who have been taught that ... (continued)

Comment: (more) ... it's a  mathematical argument. It is not. Interested readers would enjoy science historian Helge Kragh's definitive account of the history of the story.  https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.0059

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question as stated is not true. I will prove what is true - the set $M=\{A\subset \Bbb{N}:A 
\ \text{is finite}\}$ is countable.
We denote by $M_n$ all finite subsets of $\Bbb{N}$ s.t their cardinality is exactly $n$. What is the cardinality of each set?
Well, I claim that $|M_n|=\aleph_0^n=\aleph_0$. Simply define a function $\phi:M_n\rightarrow \Bbb{N}^n$ by - for every $A_n\in M_n,\phi(A_n)$ is simply the vector of length $n$ with it's coordinates being exactly the element of $A_n$, ordered by the natural order of $\Bbb{N}$.

This is obviously an injective function - and so $|M_n|=\aleph_0^n=\aleph_0$.
So, since $M=\bigcup_{n\in_\Bbb{N}}M_n$, we now see that $M$ is a countable union of countable sets and therefore countable.

The set you mentioned is ofcourse not countable, being exactly equal to $P(\Bbb{N})\setminus M$, and since $|P(\Bbb{N})|=\aleph$ and $|M|=\aleph_0$, we see that $|P(\Bbb{N})\setminus M|=\aleph$

Comment: thank you a lot I have learned a lot of all of the comments

Comment: The usual symbol for the continuum is $\mathfrak{c}$ (`\mathfrak{c}`)… or $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: $\phi$ isn't a surjection; e.g., $(0,0,\ldots,0)$ isn't in the image, unless I'm misunderstanding your definition of $\phi$. It is injective, however, so an appeal to Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein still shows $M_n$ is countably infinite.

Comment: @hayden fixed it thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot show that statement as it is false. As Micheal Barz pointed out in the comments you are probably looking for this statement here [Show that the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200389/show-that-the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-mathbbn-is-countable).

We can exhibit an uncountable subset of $M$. Namely, we have
$$ N:=\{ A \subseteq \mathbb{N} \ : \ 2\mathbb{N} +1\subseteq A  \} \subseteq M. $$
However, we have the following bijections
$$ f: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(2\mathbb{N}), S \mapsto 2S  $$
and
$$g: \mathcal{P}(2\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow N, B \mapsto B \cup (2\mathbb{N}+1).$$
We know that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is uncountable and thus, we have that $M$ and $N$ are uncountable too.

Comment: Maybe what you mean is to construct a bijection $f : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to \{ A \subseteq \mathbb{N} \mid 2\mathbb{N} \subseteq A \}$?  In which case, you would need something more like $S \mapsto 2\mathbb{N} \cup (2S + 1)$ (this formula assuming $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ - if instead you prefer $\mathbb{N}$ starting at 1, the formula would become $S \mapsto 2\mathbb{N} \cup (2S - 1)$).

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks for your comment. I actually wanted $2\mathbb{N}+1\subseteq A$, then this set is in bijection with $\mathcal{P}(2\mathbb{N}).$