# Cardinality of $A = \{E \subseteq \mathbb{N}: \exists p \text{ prime},n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that }|E| = p^n\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I am trying to find the cardinality of the set $A = \{E \subseteq \mathbb{N}: \exists p \text{ prime},m \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that }|E| = p^m\}.$

Since the set of all primes has cardinality $\aleph_0$ I feel like there could be infinitely many sets in $\mathbb{N}$ with prime cardinality. So $|A| \geq \aleph_0$. Is my intuition correct?

Comment: This is a strict subset of the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, which is countable. It's also infinite, as you note, so your set has size $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @Taladris, yes, but each set in $A$ is of finite size. This means that $A\subseteq F(\mathbb{N}),$ where $F(\mathbb{N})$ is the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}.$ In fact, $A\subset F(\mathbb{N}),$ as $\{2\}\in F(\mathbb{N})$ but $\{2\}\notin A.$

Comment: Please edit your post to clarify your question: is it your title or only your final sentence?

Comment: Instead of editing an answer, we should find some duplicate of @ConnorW's comment.

Comment: So, I should be able to find an injection $f: A \to F(\mathbb{N})$, right? @Connor W

Comment: You have to find an injection from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$. Since $A$ is already a subset of $F(\mathbb{N})$, so there is an obvious injection. As $F(N)$ is countable, it has an injection into $\mathbb{N}$. Now compose these two.  @SaimFaigol

Comment: See for example this frequently duplicated Question, [Show that the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200389/show-that-the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-mathbbn-is-countable).  I'm guessing that with that insight the road to an Answer is clear to the Original Poster.  A contextual remark about why the problem statement here is motivated would be welcome.