# Is the set of all finite integer sequences countable?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Consider the union
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}^{2n}.
$$
Is the union countable?  Each of the $\mathbb{Z}^{2n}$ is countable, and if I remember correctly the countable union of countable sets is countable but I wanted to verify this fact.

Comment: The set is countable since you can enumerate it as follows : For $k=0,1,2,\cdots$ determine all sequences with length $k$ or smaller and entries with an absolute value not larger than $k$. Each finite sequence has a finite length and a finite maximum absolute value hence it will eventually appear.

Comment: You remembered it correctly. A countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: Technically, you need a weak form of the axiom of choice in order to establish the countable union of countable sets being countable.

Comment: But here you don't. You can make everything explicit.

Comment: It does not make any difference but is there any reason why you have $\mathbb Z^{2n}$ rather than $\mathbb Z^{n}$?

Comment: @Henry no it doesn't I do not know why I bothered adding that.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/200389/399263 which is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is correct, as mentioned in the comments (using choice) a countable union of countable sets is countable. But if for each of the sets $X_i$ we a known bijection $f_i:\mathbb{N}\to X_i$.Then we can construct a surjection $f:\mathbb{N} \to \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty X_i$. It goes like this:

First, get a bijection $g:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, and define
$$f(n)=f_{\pi_1(g(n))}(\pi_2(g(n)))$$
Now any element $x^* \in X_i$ is the image of some $c$ under $f_i$ so that $k=g^{-1}(i,c)$ is such that $f(k)=x^*$, hence $f$ is surjective.

For your question, since the $X_i=\mathbb{Z}^{2n}$ are pairwise disjoint, this function $f$ is also injective as you can check, so therefore it's also bijective.