# listing all finite subsets of natural numbers

Tags: algorithms, computability, natural-numbers

is there a computable algorithm which lists all the finite subsets of natural numbers ?... i know that such a set is atleast countable... but can't determine if we can list every such subset in a computable manner .....

the set of all infinite sequences of the subsets of natural numbers is obviously uncomputable

i think this problem should be computable, since any finite set is computable... but i need some sort of proof or reference , any site etc... thanks

Comment: Specifically, the easy answer is this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/200395/87023

Comment: @ChrisCulter thanks for the link, this one nails it for me personally - https://math.stackexchange.com/a/200398/1203803   can't believe i didn't think of it at first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following algorithm lists all finite subsets of natural numbers.

```
output (empty set)
for n from 0 to infinity:
    for every subset S of {0, ..., n - 1}:
        output (S union {n})
```

It's easy to see that every finite subset of natural numbers will be output exactly once within finitely many steps.

Comment: so this is exactly this method right - https://math.stackexchange.com/a/200398/1203803

Comment: Yes I think so.